# How to continue running Bluetooth activity in background?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, bluetooth

I have a main activity in an Android app that automatically connects to a Bluetooth Arduino device, and communicates with the app. I want the app to be able to detect when it loses the Bluetooth connection, and then alert the user. This works perfectly fine when it runs completely in the foreground thread, but I want to be able to close the app, and have the user still get notified if the connection is lost. However, I'm not sure of the best method to accomplish this.

```
// Main BTLE device callback where much of the logic occurs.
public BluetoothGattCallback callback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    // Called whenever the device connection state changes, i.e. from disconnected to connected.
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            writeLine("Connected!");
            // Discover services.
            if (!gatt.discoverServices()) {
                writeLine("Failed to start discovering services!");
            }
        } else if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            writeLine("Disconnected!");
            // This is where the user is notified!
            pushNotification();

        } else {
            writeLine("Connection state changed.  New state: " + newState);
        }
    }

    // Called when services have been discovered on the remote device.
    // It seems to be necessary to wait for this discovery to occur before
    // manipulating any services or characteristics.
    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            writeLine("Service discovery completed!");
        } else {
            writeLine("Service discovery failed with status: " + status);
        }
        // Save reference to each characteristic.
        tx = gatt.getService(UART_UUID).getCharacteristic(TX_UUID);
        rx = gatt.getService(UART_UUID).getCharacteristic(RX_UUID);
        // Setup notifications on RX characteristic changes (i.e. data received).
        // First call setCharacteristicNotification to enable notification.
        if (!gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(rx, true)) {
            writeLine("Couldn't set notifications for RX characteristic!");
        }
        // Next update the RX characteristic's client descriptor to enable notifications.
        if (rx.getDescriptor(CLIENT_UUID) != null) {
            BluetoothGattDescriptor desc = rx.getDescriptor(CLIENT_UUID);
            desc.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            if (!gatt.writeDescriptor(desc)) {
                writeLine("Couldn't write RX client descriptor value!");
            }
        } else {
            writeLine("Couldn't get RX client descriptor!");
        }
    }

    // Called when a remote characteristic changes (like the RX characteristic).
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
        // THIS LINE WRITES TO THE UI FROM THE ARDUINO
        writeLine(characteristic.getStringValue(0));
    }
};

// BTLE device scanning callback.
private LeScanCallback scanCallback = new LeScanCallback() {
    // Called when a device is found.
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, int i, byte[] bytes) {
        writeLine("Found device: " + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
        // Check if the device has the UART service.
        if (parseUUIDs(bytes).contains(UART_UUID)) {
            // Found a device, stop the scan.
            adapter.stopLeScan(scanCallback);
            writeLine("Found UART service!");
            // Connect to the device.
            // Control flow will now go to the callback functions when BTLE events occur.
            gatt = bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, callback);
        }
    }
};

// OnCreate, called once to initialize the activity.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Checks if Bluetooth is enabled
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        bluetoothPopup("Your device does not support Bluetooth!");
    } else {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);;
        }
    }

    // Grab references to UI elements.
    messages = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messages);

    //adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    adapter = mBluetoothAdapter;
}

// OnResume, called right before UI is displayed.  Start the BTLE connection.
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Scan for all BTLE devices.
    // The first one with the UART service will be chosen--see the code in the scanCallback.
    writeLine("Scanning for devices...");
    adapter.startLeScan(scanCallback);
}

// OnStop, called right before the activity loses foreground focus.  Close the BTLE connection.
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (gatt != null) {
        // For better reliability be careful to disconnect and close the connection.
        gatt.disconnect();
        gatt.close();
        gatt = null;
        tx = null;
        rx = null;
    }
}

// Write some text to the messages text view.
// Care is taken to do this on the main UI thread so writeLine can be called
// from any thread (like the BTLE callback).
private void writeLine(final CharSequence text) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            messages.append(text);
            messages.append("\n");
        }
    });
}

// This is a workaround function from the SO thread to manually parse advertisement data.
private List<UUID> parseUUIDs(final byte[] advertisedData) {
    List<UUID> uuids = new ArrayList<UUID>();

    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < (advertisedData.length - 2)) {
        int len = advertisedData[offset++];
        if (len == 0)
            break;

        int type = advertisedData[offset++];
        switch (type) {
            case 0x02: // Partial list of 16-bit UUIDs
            case 0x03: // Complete list of 16-bit UUIDs
                while (len > 1) {
                    int uuid16 = advertisedData[offset++];
                    uuid16 += (advertisedData[offset++] << 8);
                    len -= 2;
                    uuids.add(UUID.fromString(String.format("%08x-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", uuid16)));
                }
                break;
            case 0x06:// Partial list of 128-bit UUIDs
            case 0x07:// Complete list of 128-bit UUIDs
                // Loop through the advertised 128-bit UUID's.
                while (len >= 16) {
                    try {
                        // Wrap the advertised bits and order them.
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(advertisedData, offset++, 16).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                        long mostSignificantBit = buffer.getLong();
                        long leastSignificantBit = buffer.getLong();
                        uuids.add(new UUID(leastSignificantBit,
                                mostSignificantBit));
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        // Defensive programming.
                        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                        continue;
                    } finally {
                        // Move the offset to read the next uuid.
                        offset += 15;
                        len -= 16;
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                offset += (len - 1);
                break;
        }
    }
    return uuids;
}

// Method called to start the service
public void startService(View view) {
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AppService.class));
}

// Method called to stop the service
public void stopService(View view) {
    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AppService.class));}
```

The connection will already be established before the service begins, but how do I ensure that the connection will still be maintained when the service starts? Do I just need to pass the BluetoothGattCallback callback object to the service, and what is the best way to do that?

--UPDATE-
I figured the best way to do this is through a service, but how would I pass it a complex parameter such as the "callback" object? How would I do this using the Parcelable interface?

Comment: use a service and bind the activity to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `Service`.
It may be a good idea, depending on your needs, to show your app is running as a Notification - this way it won't get automatically killed, but you are always aware it is running.  If that is what you want, you want a `ForegroundService`.

Full tutorial here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

`Activities` are bound to their visible part. If they are not visible they can get destroyed. For background tasks you need a headless component. You usually use a `Service`as such.